# Is it possible to start an asyncio event loop in the background without spawning a thread or process?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a service implemented in Python 3.5 that should load a file over the network periodically. I would like to avoid blocking the main thread while it loads. In order to avoid introducing the complexity of threads and shared memory to my application, I wanted to use an event loop with the asyncio package to instrument this.

To run an event loop, I've found the `AbstractEventLoop.run_forever()` and `AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete(future)` methods, but both seem to be blocking the main thread when called. The only way I've found to avoid this is to start the loop in a different thread. But then if I'm using threads anyway, there is no point in using an event loop.

So my question is: Is it possible to start an asyncio event loop in the background without spawning a thread or process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `run_in_executor` method. Each of the functions you run with this method run in their own thread (in parallel).

> The AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor() method can be used with a thread pool executor to execute a callback in different thread to not block the thread of the event loop.
>
> The executor argument should be an Executor instance. The default executor is used if executor is None.

For example:

```
import asyncio

def load_file_over_network(file_name):
    # do the file loading
    pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
file_name = 'FILE_NAME'

# load the file without blocking
loop.run_in_executor(None, load_file_over_network, file_name)

# do some other stuff in the main thread
# while the synchronous code above is running in other threads, the event loop
# can go do other things

# load the file again without blocking
loop.run_in_executor(None, load_file_over_network, file_name)
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: hmmm... I would say this answer is wrong.  In python's docs  [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor) is marked as a coroutine - which means it should be awaited to work properly.  However, currently it isn't implemented as a coroutine, but returns an `asyncio.Future` instead.  I.e., `run_in_executor()` should be running within an event loop: Try getting the return value of `load_file_over_network()` from the "main thread".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! So the call should be `asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(...))` ?

Comment: This answer is not responsive to the question.  The question asks how to start an event loop without blocking the main thread or using threads.

Answer (score 2):

If your whole program runs without `asyncio`'s event loop, running only one task in a new event loop does not make a lot of sense.   Instead, try using the much less complex [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library.  Any task called would immediately return a `Future` instance which has a `.done()` and `.result()` methods:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor


def fetcher():
    print("fetching...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("got it!")
    return 42


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    fut = None
    for i in range(100):
        if i % 10 == 2:
            fut = executor.submit(fetcher)
        print(i, fut)
        if fut and fut.done():
            result = fut.result()  # can raise an error
            print("Done! Got:", result)
            fut = None
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Could you explain the rationale about _"running only one task in a new event loop does not make a lot of sense."_ ? (so even someone without knowledge about `asyncio` understands it)

Comment: In the question above the author have mentioned he already have a program written without `asyncio` (his "main thread").  Using `asyncio`, this "main thread" would need to be modified to be able to work without blocking another thread.  `concurrent futures` allows you to add another thread without modifying existing code.

Comment: Since I'm currently running a separate thread via `run_in_executor` while the main thread is not. I'm still confused about why this would _not make sense_. Are there any negative side effects?

Comment: doesn't the question ask specifically for a solution that doesn't utilize additional threads or processes?  From your answer it seems as if you are using an additional thread.

Comment: @Marc: My answer does not use an event loop at all, just threads.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [Yuval Pruss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43451596/1763602) is right, partially. Indeed, the [`Executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) parameter of `loop.run_in_executor()` can be a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (the default), or a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

So the answer is no, you can't run an `asyncio` `Task` in background with all the other code synchronous. Or you rewrite your application so it uses `asyncio` for every task, or you have to use threads or processes.

Comment: Why `ProcessPoolExecutor` is deprecated in asyncio ?

Comment: @remort: sorry, it's deprecated (and now removed) to set it as default executor. I correct the answer.